# How do I show that if there is a diffeomorphism between two smooth manifolds, the manifolds have the same dimension?

Tags: differential-geometry

I think I've somehow got to bring tangent spaces into the picture, but how do I solve this?

Comment: What have you done so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dimension of a manifold is the same as the dimension (as a real vector space) of its tangent space. A diffeomorphism between manifolds induces (at each point) an isomorphism of the corresponding tangent spaces.